# How t0 replace array or object element and remove unused duplicate ones

Tags: java, replace

I have a arraylist with below values.

```
new Car[make:"omni",color:"red"]

new Car[make:"swift",color:"blue"]

new Car[make:"swift",color:"red"]

new Car[make:"swift",color:"white"]

new Car[make:"omni",color:"blue"]
```

I want to make a list out of this which should return Car 
make as below.

```
new Car[make:"omni",color:"red","blue"]
```

Could you please let me know the code in java to do this?

Thanks for the response in advance.

Comment: Why is the Swift car model logically being removed here?  Note that a better design in this case would be to have the `color` field in your class modeled using a collection, rather than a string.

Comment: This is not Java, please use the right tags

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. But, please make sure to add minimal reproducible code next time to show what you have tried so far and where you struck.
Car.java.

```
public class Car {
private String make;
private String color;

public Car() {

}

public Car(String make, String color) {
    this.make = make;
    this.color = color;
}

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "make:" + this.getMake() + "," + "color:" + this.getColor();
}
```

}

Main Method

```
`public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    cars.add(new Car("omni", "black"));
    cars.add(new Car("swift", "blue"));
    cars.add(new Car("omni", "red"));
    cars.add(new Car("swift", "black"));
    cars.add(new Car("omni", "blue"));

    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (resultMap.containsKey(car.getMake())) {
            resultMap.put(car.getMake(), resultMap.get(car.getMake()) + "," + car.getColor());
        } else {
            resultMap.put(car.getMake(), car.getColor());
        }
    }

    List<Car> finalCars = resultMap.entrySet().stream().map(mapper -> {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setMake(mapper.getKey());
        car.setColor(mapper.getValue());
        return car;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    finalCars.forEach(car -> {
        System.out.println(car.toString());
    });
}`
```